# SKStoreProductViewController or similar solution possible for websites?

Tags: web, download, app-store

We would like that when the visitor of our website clicks on the appstore button to download the app, he is not redirected to the appstore but a popup of the appstore appears where he can download the app.
This function already exists in some apps and is called "SKStoreProductViewController".
We would now like to include this on our website so that our customers stay on the website when they download the app.
We do not want to bypass the app store

Answer (score 0):

As you stated yourself this is used in native apps. You want to use it in a browser, i.e. not possible.

Using Smart App Banners is probably as close as you can get in a browser: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners

Or you "fake" the app store and build your own modal, which then links to the store page.